# Pytorch transform tensor to one hot

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, one-hot-encoding

What is the easiest way to transform tensor of shape (batch_size, height, width) filled with `n` values to tensor of shape (batch_size, n, height, width)? 
I created solution below, but looks like there are easier and faster way to do this

```
def batch_tensor_to_onehot(tnsr, classes):
    tnsr = tnsr.unsqueeze(1)
    res = []
    for cls in range(classes):
        res.append((tnsr == cls).long())
    return torch.cat(res, dim=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [torch.nn.functional.one_hot](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.one_hot).

For your case:

```
a = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(tnsr, num_classes=classes)
out = a.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
```

Comment: I want to use the following tensor and get a list of one-hot that only have 10 columns. Because when using this list, one_hot returns vectors with more columns (the number of column is based on the maximum value in the target list). Here is an example: `x = torch.tensor([100,1,58,98,35,64,72,1659,873]`. When using one_hot for the x list, I have got 1660 columns, instead of 10 columns. Thank you

Comment: What's the reason for the usage of permute function and why such arguments? @one

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`Tensor.scatter_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_) which avoids `.permute` but is arguably more difficult to understand than the straightforward method proposed by @Alpha.

```
def batch_tensor_to_onehot(tnsr, classes):
    result = torch.zeros(tnsr.shape[0], classes, *tnsr.shape[1:], dtype=torch.long, device=tnsr.device)
    result.scatter_(1, tnsr.unsqueeze(1), 1) 
    return result
```

---

### Benchmarking Results

I was curious and decided to benchmark the three approaches. I found that there doesn't appear to be a significant relative difference between the proposed methods with respect to batch-size, width, or height. Primarily the number of classes was the distinguishing factor. Of course as with any benchmark mileage may vary.

The benchmarks were collected using random indices and using batch-size, height, width = 100. Each experiment was repeated 20 times with the average being reported. The num_classes=100 experiment is run once before profiling for warmup.

The CPU results show that the original method was probably best for num_classes less than about 30, while for GPU the `scatter_` approach seems to be fastest.

Tests performed on Ubuntu 18.04, NVIDIA 2060 Super, i7-9700K

[image]

[image]

Code used for benchmarking is provided below:

```
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def batch_tensor_to_onehot_slavka(tnsr, classes):
    tnsr = tnsr.unsqueeze(1)
    res = []
    for cls in range(classes):
        res.append((tnsr == cls).long())
    return torch.cat(res, dim=1)


def batch_tensor_to_onehot_alpha(tnsr, classes):
    result = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(tnsr, num_classes=classes)
    return result.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)


def batch_tensor_to_onehot_jodag(tnsr, classes):
    result = torch.zeros(tnsr.shape[0], classes, *tnsr.shape[1:], dtype=torch.long, device=tnsr.device)
    result.scatter_(1, tnsr.unsqueeze(1), 1)
    return result


def main():
    num_classes = [2, 10, 25, 50, 100]
    height = 100
    width = 100
    bs = [100] * 20

    for d in ['cpu', 'cuda']:
        times_slavka = []
        times_alpha = []
        times_jodag = []
        warmup = True
        for c in tqdm([num_classes[-1]] + num_classes, ncols=0):
            tslavka = 0
            talpha = 0
            tjodag = 0

            for b in bs:
                tnsr = torch.randint(c, (b, height, width)).to(device=d)

                t0 = time.time()
                y = batch_tensor_to_onehot_slavka(tnsr, c)
                torch.cuda.synchronize()
                tslavka += time.time() - t0
            if not warmup:
                times_slavka.append(tslavka / len(bs))

            for b in bs:
                tnsr = torch.randint(c, (b, height, width)).to(device=d)

                t0 = time.time()
                y = batch_tensor_to_onehot_alpha(tnsr, c)
                torch.cuda.synchronize()
                talpha += time.time() - t0
            if not warmup:
                times_alpha.append(talpha / len(bs))

            for b in bs:
                tnsr = torch.randint(c, (b, height, width)).to(device=d)

                t0 = time.time()
                y = batch_tensor_to_onehot_jodag(tnsr, c)
                torch.cuda.synchronize()
                tjodag += time.time() - t0
            if not warmup:
                times_jodag.append(tjodag / len(bs))


            warmup = False

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.subplots()
        ax.plot(num_classes, times_slavka, label='Slavka-cat')
        ax.plot(num_classes, times_alpha, label='Alpha-one_hot')
        ax.plot(num_classes, times_jodag, label='jodag-scatter_')
        ax.set_xlabel('num_classes')
        ax.set_ylabel('time (s)')
        ax.set_title(f'{d} benchmark')
        ax.legend()
        plt.savefig(f'{d}.png')
        plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```